# iOS simultaneous recording by all microphones

Tags: ios, iphone, audio-recording

I am looking for a way to record sound on the iPhone from all microphones at the same time or at least two to record stereo. I looked through several topics on the English version of this resource, but all the topics were created before 2017, and they say that such a recording is not possible due to the single-channel incoming audio stream.

Further searches prompted information that the iPhone XS can write video with stereo sound.

Dear colleagues, kindly tell me how to solve this problem or at least where to look.